# How did $(x+y)^{-2}$ suddenly turn into that?

Tags: calculus

[From Calculus Made Easy]

\begin{align*}
y+dy&=(x+dx)^{-2}\\
&=x^{-2}\left(1+\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{-2}
\end{align*}

Is there some formula I'm not aware of?

Comment: Your picture does not match your title and is cut off.  In the picture they just distribute $x^2$ out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a slight variation of the following trick:

$$ (a + b)^2 = \left( a \left(1 + \frac ba \right) \right)^2 = a^2 \left( 1 + \frac ba \right)^2$$

Comment: Is there a proof for this trick?

Comment: It's just the distributive property (you factor out an $a$ from both terms of the binomial) followed by the exponent rule $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$.

Comment: @privilegedMale A proof is just to evaluate both sides and show, that they are indeed even.